# The new Google Preview renders flash areas as empty blocks

Tags: flash, seo

Is anyone else seeing this is there any real information about how / when and what kinds of rendering rules there? I don't even know if the preview is live or cached. Googling for google preview is not all that helpful, I don't see any guides or help files coming up.

Answer (score 0):

well, your question is kind of ... big, best see the official google preview FAQ http://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-instant-previews

but as a matter of fact, don't care too much, i have access to some big sites, some of them render correctly in google preview, some have some challenges. the impact on traffic was 0.